# Retrieve specific field while doing eager loading in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I am new to laravel and I am using laravel 5.3
I am having a user table which is made up of 18 fields. Any time I run this line: `$article->load('comments.user', 'comments.replies.user');`, I am getting all the 18 fields. Is there any possibility to retrieve only 3 fields (name, username and id) ?

I have spent some time searching on google but the answer I found, does not work:

```
$article->load(array('comments.user' => function($query) {
  $query->select('id', 'name', 'username');
}));
```

Comment: Try using: $query->select('id', 'name', 'username')->get();

Comment: @john Thanks, It is working as desired. Can you post your answer please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `$article->load('comments.user', 'comments.replies.user');` can be changed to the following lines of code where the desired fields can be specified

```
return $article->load(
    array(
        'comments.user' => function($query) {
            $query->select('id', 'name', 'username')->get();
        },
        'comments.replies.user' => function($query) {
            $query->select('id', 'name', 'username')->get();
        }
    )
);
```